# Planes and intersection problem linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the plane $A$ and $B$ given by equations

A) $x+y-z=1$

B) $x-y+2z=-1$

and let P be the point $(2,1,1)$.
Write down the equation of the plane passing through the point P
and the line $L$ of intersection of $A$ and $B$.

Find the coordinates of the intersection of the line L and the plane

$2x-5y+z=4$.

What I did I solve the two equation for $x=0$ which gave me the point which I call $Q$ $(0,1,0)$ and then I found $PQ$ which is $(-2,0,-1)$
Found the cross product of the equations $(1,3,-2)$
found the cross product of PQ and the Normal vector
which is $(3i,-5j,-6k)$
and then im stuck on how to write the equation and finding the coordinates.
Any advice?

Comment: The normal vector to *what*?

Comment: oh sorry I write it wrong I meant the cross product of the first two equationn, let me correct it

Comment: You mean the cross product of the normal vectors to the planes given by the equations, I guess?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: *A simpler way to solve the  problem*

A plane passing through the intersection line of the planes A and B belongs to the sheaf of planes defined by A and B, and has equation
$$\lambda(x+y-z)+\mu(x-y+2z)=\lambda-\mu,\qquad\lambda,\mu\in\mathbf R\;\text{not both }0.$$
Just write the point $P$ satisfies this equation to obtain the ratio $\lambda/\mu$.